# Private Function skipping For Loop

Tags: excel, vba, dictionary

I am trying to now learn how Dictionaries work within VBA, so I created a simple Class Module, A Function, and then two subs, but for reasons beyond me the `For` loop is completely skipped within the function.  Below is the Code for all of the items mentioned above.  I do have the Microsoft Scripting Runtime checked in Tools > References.  Im not really familiar with how Late and Early Binding are utilized, so I'm wondering if that's one of the issues.

Currently the `Set rg = LoanData.Range("AH2")` is in a table, I have tried the data in that range as both a table and also as just a range, but the `For` Loop in the function is skipped if the data is in a Table or not.

[image: Data Set]

**Class Module called clsCounty**

```
Public CountyID As Long
Public County As String
```

**Function called ReadCounty**

```
Private Function ReadCounty() As Dictionary
    Dim dict As New Dictionary

    Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = LoanData.Range("AH2")

    Dim oCounty As clsCounty, i As Long


    For i = 2 To rg.Rows.Count

        Set oCounty = New clsCounty

        oCounty.CountyID = rg.Cells(i, 1).Value
        oCounty.County = rg.Cells(i, 2).Value

        dict.Add oCounty.CountyID, oCounty
    Next i

    Set ReadCounty = dict


End Function
```

**The two subs to write to the immediate window**

```
Private Sub WriteToImmediate(dict As Dictionary)
    Dim key As Variant, oCounty As clsCounty

    For Each key In dict.Keys
        Set oCounty = dict(key)
        With oCounty
            Debug.Print .CountyID, .County
        End With
    Next key

End Sub

Sub Main()
    Dim dict As Dictionary

    Set dict = ReadCounty

    WriteToImmediate dict

End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you define `LoanData`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You've declared your range as `Set rg = LoanData.Range("AH2")` and then use `For i = 2 To rg.Rows.Count` in your loop. the `rg.Rows.Count` will be `1` as there is only 1 cell in your range. This is before the starting value for your `For` loop (`2`) so it won't do anything.

i.e. `For i = 2 to 1`

Declare your `rg` variable with the full range. I'm going to guess something like

```
With LoanData
    Set rg = .Range(.Cells(1,"AH"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "AH").End(xlUp).Row, "AH"))
End With
```

Comment: Thanks!  such a simple miss on my part.  This now works as expected and now its time to figure out how to actually call on the data that is stored in the dictionary :).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is indeed in the usage of `Set rg = LoanData.Range("AH2")`, [as mentioned in the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56526756/5448626).

However, to be a bit more elegant, you may consider using `LastRow`, function, which takes as arguments `columnToCheck` and `wsName`:

```
Public Function LastRow(wsName As String, Optional columnToCheck As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets(wsName)
    LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, columnToCheck).End(xlUp).Row

End Function
```

In the code, it would look like this:

```
Private Function ReadCounty() As Dictionary

    Dim dict As New Dictionary
    Dim oCounty As clsCounty, i As Long

    'For i = 2 To LastRow("LoanData", 34)
    For i = 2 To LastRow(LoanData.Name, Range("AH1").Column) 
        Set oCounty = New clsCounty
        oCounty.CountyID = LoanData.Cells(i, "AH").Value
        oCounty.County = LoanData.Cells(i, "AI").Value
        dict.Add oCounty.CountyID, oCounty
    Next i

    Set ReadCounty = dict

End Function
```

Comment: Thank you.  Once i figure out how to return the item from the Dictionary based on a value in a cell I will give this a shot.

Comment: How's this more 'elegant'? You've just broken one line out into a function

Comment: @Tom - yes but the function can be (and will be) reused and the parameters are understandable. In the 1 line, AH is passed 3 times and you need to read it at least 2-3 times to get what is happenning.

Comment: Furthermore, the 1 line from the other answer gets the range, while the function returns the last row only, which could be used as a module part later.